# DK2 Head tracking not working "HMD powered off, check HDMI connection" on Windows

Tags: windows, oculus, webvr, firefox-nightly, oculus-runtime

### Part 1 - Description of the problem

I have the `DK2` and I am working on a `VR` project. This project uses FirefoxNightly. I've downloaded it and installed the `WebVR Enabler Add-On`

[image: getting started webvr]

Got this from http://mozvr.com/downloads/

---

I have also downloaded and installed the latest SDK and Runtime for Windows from https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/

[image: getting started 2 webvr]

---

I am also getting this on the Oculus Configuration Utility (while the oculus is plugged in):

[image: occulus configuration utility]

However, I have gone on another computer with windows.. installed everything just like on this windows computer and it clearly shows the Oculus Rift connected properly but the head tracking still not working.

**EDIT:** I just tried connecting the oculus rift to this "second" pc ( dell laptop ) and now it doesn't even recognize the oculus rift. Still no head tracking.

**EDIT 2:** I tried installing everything on a third PC without success. I'm getting **"service unavailable"** on the Oculus Configuration Utility

---

My display mode is set as shown in the image.

[image: extend display mode]

---

### Part 2 - Questions

What am I doing wrong? Is there a step I forgot to do? The weird thing is, I have the same project running on Mac without having any problems. Yes, on windows I can see the screen through the `oculus rift` but head detection is just not present.

### Part 3 - list of possible fixes that did not work

[This reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/2cbgxl/dk2_no_head_tracking_at_all_not_just_positional/) talks about the firewall issue however I tried the oculus rift with the firewall disactivated without success.

[This reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/2cu0qq/how_i_got_my_dk2_working_with_positional_tracking/) talks about a possible fix by reinstalling everything and updating certain drivers.. however I have followed this fix step by step without success.

[This oculus forum](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=23379&sid=1c1389bdd044eea4e146ba578b21dc0f&start=20) post talks about the issue and one person proposes a fix that worked for him/her. I followed the fix without success.

### Part 4 - System info

If you require specific translations let me know. It is in French.

[image: System info]

### Part 5 - List of things I have tried that have been thought of

1. I have reinstalled everything. SDK (is not even needed in fact), runtime, firefoxnightly, webvr add-on multiple times
2. I have rebooted my computer multiple times
3. I have tried the different `Rift Display Mode`
4. Basic demos from mozvr.com and other webvr based projects work fine but head tracking does not work.
5. My Oculus is not broken (maybe for windows), it works fine for the Mac.
6. I've tried using different HDMI cables and Different minUSB-USB cables without success.

### Part 6 - Quotes from the forum

[First post](https://answers.oculus.com/questions/4475/hmd-sensor-detected-check-hdmi-connection-06.html)

> This sounds like the same issue a lot of us are having with the 0.5
>   and 0.6 versions. It's not something wrong with the cables, but with
>   the Runtime itself. Direct-mode works flawlessly and in Extended mode
>   the rift still displays a picture, altho without any tracking etc from
>   the runtime. Hoping it'll be fixed in the next update.

Comment: Is tracking broken in just your project or is it broken for the [mozvr.com](http://mozvr.com/projects/) and [webvr-boilerplate](http://borismus.github.io/webvr-boilerplate/) examples as well?

Comment: Does the Oculus Demo Scene or other native Oculus apps work for you on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, most games made for the Oculus Rift are based on specific versions of the Oculus Rift. I found [this GUI desktop application](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/4ckm38/oculus_runtime_switcher_0506070813_with_gui/) that seems to solve most of those problems.

The idea is to install all Oculus Rift Runtime versions and then use the GUI to switch between each version.

The link above is to a reddit post that talks about how to install the application and the different runtimes.

You must install the runtimes from oldest to newest otherwise you'll run into some difficulties, like I unfortunately did. If I'm not mistaken runtime version 0.8 is very buggy and I never really got it to work.

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen head tracking break in Firefox Nightly sometimes but I can usually solve it by restarting the browser once or twice, assuming that the hardware and Oculus side of things is working correctly.

Comment: @Grimbode Yeah, I don't think this has anything to do with WebVR. I think it's an issue with the Oculus side of things. I believe I've experienced this problem as well. It might be specific to the latest drivers. Other people have reported the issue on the [forums](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=23379&sid=1c1389bdd044eea4e146ba578b21dc0f&start=20) and [Oculus Answers](https://answers.oculus.com/questions/4475/hmd-sensor-detected-check-hdmi-connection-06.html). I think my solution was to switch back and forth between extended and direct mode while unplugging the Rift in between.

Comment: Well, if you're interested, I can Skype you to help you figure it out. Find me on twitter @brianpeiris

Comment: @Grimbode Yup, I should be available on Monday.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get the Oculus **DK2** working on my **Windows 10 Laptop**:

- Create a windows restore point before you start this.
- Download `oculus_runtime_rev_1_sdk_0.4.4_win.exe` from the [Oculus downloads page.](https://developer3.oculus.com/downloads/)
- Run the installer. Do **not** restart your computer when prompted.
- Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Oculus\Service` folder, right click on `OVRServer_x86.exe` and go to properties.
- In the compatibility tab, check Windows 8 mode, and Run As Administrator.
- Run `OVRServer_x86.exe`

That's it.

#### The Good News

You should now be able to run direct to rift games. The [HELIX rollercoaster](http://www.theriftarcade.com/helix-rollercoaster/) app works well. So does the [6000 Moons](http://binsoftware.com/moons/) demo. Most others do not. Depending on the game, you may need to go to your windows display settings, and fiddle with the screen resolution and rotation of the Oculus display.

#### The Bad News

Your computer may not restart. When I did the above, and later restarted, the computer hung on the windows loading page. I had to go into advanced start mode and load a system restore point. Definitely not the best user experience, but at least I got something working.